# libclang fails to parse the classes with :: in name

Tags: python, c++, libclang

I'm using libclang+python binding to parse the cpp files, but it fails to parse the following class:

```cpp
class ReadableStreamBytesConsumer::OnFulfilled final : public ScriptFunction {
    static v8::Local<v8::Function> CreateFunction(){}
}
```

libclang does not extract the function "CreateFunction()" for me. However, if I erase ReadableStreamBytesConsumer and make the code like:

```cpp
class OnFulfilled final : public ScriptFunction {
    static v8::Local<v8::Function> CreateFunction(){}
}
```

It works well, but I need to parse the first piece of code, anyone can help here?

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting? It works fine for me: https://godbolt.org/z/EPjb6qo5f in pseudo scenario code. This works too: https://godbolt.org/z/MWE6oqcfs

Comment: Sorry I described question inappropriately, libclang fails if I write class name as "class ReadableStreamBytesConsumer::OnFulfilled". I use "get_children()" to retrieve "CreateFunction()", but there's no such children.